# CSS: find the cause of a large whitespace in a page

Tags: html, css

I've got the following CSS code, which is somehow causing a very large white space after my header image.  Can you guys help me determine where this is coming from?

[image]

Here's the CSS, do you see where I'm making a mistake here?

```
   body {
   font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

    #report { width: 835px; }

    table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: none;
    font: 10pt Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

    table td{
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

    table th {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

h2{ clear: both; font-size: 130%;color:#354B5E;position:relative;}

h3{
    clear: both;
    font-size: 75%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    color:#475F77;
}

h4{
    clear: both;
    font-size: 90%;

    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color:#475F44;
}

.wrap {
    font-size: 60%;    
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color:#FFFFFF;      
    position:relative;
background:#466788;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    }

    #header, #footer {
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
        right: 0%;
        z-index:999999;
        background:#466788;
            /*text-align: right;*/
        color:#FFFFFF;
        width:100%;
    }

img { 
position: relative; 
top: 0; 
left: 0;
width : 100%; 
margin-bottom : 500px;
} 

p{ margin-left: 20px; 
     font-size: 12px; }

table.list{ float: left; }

    table.list td:nth-child(1){
    font-weight: bold;
    border-right: 1px grey solid;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
}

table.list td:nth-child(2){ padding-left: 7px; }
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even){ background: #BBBBBB; }
table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd){ background: #F2F2F2; }
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd){ background: #DDDDDD; }
table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even){ background: #E5E5E5; }
div.column { width: 320px; float: left; }
div.first{ padding-right: 20px; border-right: 1px  grey solid; }
div.second{ margin-left: 30px; }
table{ margin-left: 20px; }
```

and the HTML

```
<title>Migrations for 2014-06-11 0800</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file://dellbook/Migmon/MigMon.css" />
</head><body>
<img src="\\DELLBOOK\Migmon\logo.jpg" width=100%><h2>Migration Group: <b>2014-06-11 0800</b></h2><P>Great work today, all remaining computers for this Migration group are marked as 'Migration Completed' in SharePoint.</P>
<table id="my_table">
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<thead>
<tr><th>MigrationStatus</th><th>User</th><th>ComputerName</th><th>Location</th><th>Ipv4</th><th>Domain</th><th>Online</th></tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: In your code you have `margin-bottom : 500px;` within `img` if the logo is the only image used, that would explain a gap of 500px underneath.

Comment: You might want to start using a debugging tool like Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your problem:

```
margin-bottom : 500px;
```

Here:

```
img { 
position: relative; 
top: 0; 
left: 0;
width : 100%; 
margin-bottom : 500px;
}
```

Remove it or update it to be like:

```
margin-bottom : 0;
```

Comment: Nice one, you answer 37 seconds before me.

Comment: Wow, this is so close, I think you win the award for quickest response.  Thanks a lot Luthando, this has resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
img
{
margin-bottom:500px;
}

that's the issue
```

Comment: Thank you Kentoro, both you and Luthando answered at the same time, so I'm upvoting both responses.

Comment: @FoxDeploy Happy to help, by the way that HTML looks a little old school, I would put the logo inside the header element for HTML5, and the rest inside a section element if article is not appropiate.

<body><header>
<img src="\\DELLBOOK\Migmon\logo.jpg" width=100%></header><section><h2>Migrations</h2></section>

Comment: Care to offer an example of how I should do this?  It is admittedly old school code, because I'm new to CSS :)

Comment: Here is a better link for it: http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have margin-bottom : 500px; within img. If the logo is the only image used, that would explain a gap of 500px underneath.

Answer (score 1):

Within your *img* selector you have set a margin on the bottom.

In this section of code:

```
    img { 
        position: relative; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0;
        width : 100%; 
        margin-bottom : 500px;
    }
```

This line is your problem:

```
margin-bottom : 500px;
```

Try deleting this line or changing it to a value you wish.